# Error when installing FirebaseAuth.unitypackage, Gradle failed to fetch dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I installed the google json to my project, and the FirebaseAuth.unitypackage, aswell. While the Firebase.Auth.unitypackage was being added the console displayed "Gradle failed to fetch dependencies". I updated my play services resolver to 1.2.50.00 by deleting the previous one and imported the new one into my project as another post said but no fix. I also tried /Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Resolve and Force resolve.

**The console logs:**

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat -b Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Users/Augmented Marketing/Downloads/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\Augmented Marketing\Documents\Unity firebase test\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:///C:/Users/Augmented Marketing/Documents/Unity firebase test/Assets/Firebase/m2repository" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.2.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:4.1.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:4.1.0"'
stdout:

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.315 secs

stderr:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Augmented Marketing\Documents\Unity firebase test\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle' line: 129

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'PlayServicesResolverGradle'.
> Illegal character in path at index 26: file:///C:/Users/Augmented Marketing/Documents/Unity firebase test/Assets/Firebase/m2repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

exit code: 1

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:<PlayServicesResolver>m__0(String, LogLevel)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, LogLevel, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file.

Comment: @TonnyBaya I searched google and cannot locate where this file is in my unity project

Comment: My apologies did not see you are developing with Unity.

Comment: @TonnyBaya Maybe this is similar to android build.gradle, whereabouts is the location of that file in android studio projects?

Comment: In android studio the file is usually inside ./app/build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Can you try change the folder name `Unityfirebasetest` instead of `Unity firebase test` and `AugmentedMarketing` instead of `Augmented Marketing` in `C:\Users\Augmented Marketing\Documents\Unity firebase test` ? 
So, remove the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is whitespace in your project path.  We fixed this in the 4.2.0 release of the Firebase SDK https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.2.0 and in https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/commit/bf515eb2080ee9713584684521d36ad7e8d62fbd of the Play Services Resolver.

Cheers,
Stewart